# Problem Booting from USB Stick on Old Dell Laptop

Tags: boot, usb, dell

I'm running Ubuntu 8.10 on an old Dell Latitude laptop and would like to upgrade to Ubuntu 13.10. I was able to make a bootable USB Stick but the Dell won't boot from it. I hit f12 as it booted and got the BIOS menu but there is no USB option. So I thought about making a CD (the Dell can't read DVD). I have a desktop running Windows 7 that I could make a DVD or CD, but again, the Dell won't read DVD and the CD doesn't have the room for the files. What to do? My apologies if this has already been answered somewhere - I looked thru many of the answers but didn't see any that answered my dilemma.

Comment: Also a still recent Ubuntu version (and supported for an even longer time) is 12.04. It fits onto a CD. Maybe it's good enough for your target machine. You can download it here: http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04

Answer (score 1):

I too have a very old Dell (Inspiron 1000) and it recognizes the flash drive as another hard drive.  Go to the BIOS and you will notice a + by the hard drive entry.  Click on that and you will see the flash drive.  Simply move it to the top, save, and exit.  You will then be able to boot from the flash drive.